# android emulator error

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anybody tell me why my android emulator gives the following error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a bigger partition size, assuming your avd is called `Droid` from the console you can:

```
emulator -partition-size 512 -avd Droid
```

will start `Droid` with `512mb`of internal storage.

Comment: stillit gives error[2010-12-27 13:25:05 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Answer (score 1):

When your creating an avd in eclipse, give it some more space.  Read [Android Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) for more information. Basically where it says SD card, give it some extra space.  I usually give mine at least 10 mb.